# Jenkins respect HEAD or default branch when cloning repo to workspace

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins provides lengthy documentation regarding how to specify which branches it will build from. https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/

None of that though answers this specific question, or if it does, I cannot seem to achieve this.

**How to specify that Jenkins will use whichever branch is normally checked out when cloning, such as the default branch specified in Github**

Does this even make sense or is this even possible?

**EDIT: specifically what should go in the red circle to checkout the default branch in Github**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins respects the default branch over HEAD. Also, it depends how you configure you Jenkins job if it's a mulit-branch pipeline then you don't need to specify which branch it should build, by default it will scan you GitHub repo and build the changes made on branch and it will trigger the build.

If it's pipeline job then you can specify which branch it should built by editing the job configuration on Jenkins job and specifying the particular branch name in the section `Branches to build`

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Ty for responding. I'm trying to configure this for a freestyle project. It asks which branch you want to build from, and I want to build from HEAD, basically, the default branch configured in Github. I've tried a lot of different refs and none seem to work